# How Update RDD In Spark with FILTER

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have a RDD file that have two columns O and D. There is a edges between each values of the columns. For example,

| O | D |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| b | g |
| c | t |
| g | a |

That mean a related to b... And I need to have file like this but with filter all nodes that do not appear to column O. Here we will do the same without the row c -- t because t not appear in column O. I try something that seem to work. I do list with all the column O and filter all value of D that not appear in this list

```
list_O = df.select('O').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
df1 = df.filter(df.D.isin(list_O)).show()
```

And when I want to see the head of this new rdd it is error

```
df1.head(5)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNC1u.png)
I don't understand why.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend against the use of `collect` for that use case, if you're working with large data it will likely blow with an OOM error as you're collecting all data locally. How about using an inner join instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have an idea. The function .show() returns None. Remove the .show() (it is only supposed to print things). df1 is set to None in your code.

```
list_O = df.select('O').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
df1 = df.filter(df.D.isin(list_O))
```